# How to convert utf-8 to cp1250 in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, utf-8

I need convert data from wchar_t with utf-8 to cp-1250 (latin-2). Anybody know, how it do? I used this code:

```
const char *textZwievData = [textToSynthesize cStringUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1250StringEncoding];
const wchar_t *textZwievDataPriprava = (wchar_t *)textZwievData;
```

but i have trouble with two letters, its "š" and "ž". So anybody know, how it do together with this letters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is bad parameter in cStringUsingEncoding. Instead NSWindowsCP1250StringEncoding, use NSISOLatin2StringEncoding and problem is out.